# IIS max concurrent user limit reached

Tags: asp.net, iis

Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 6.2 build 9200.  We're hosted in Azure, and lean heavily on Redis for caching.

Received an IIS error on our site yesterday which coincided with ~1k concurrent users:

`max concurrent user limit reached`

In IIS settings under `Advanced settings` -> `Limits` the `Maximum Concurrent Connections` property is set to `4294967295`

What else might cause this error?  It seems to of brought our website down and forced us to reboot to fix.  Our pages all do some sort of heavyish work (anywhere from 20ms to 100ms in rendering time).

Comment: This may be caused by the number of user connections exceeding the queueLength property in applicationPools. queueLength: Indicates to HTTP.sys how many requests to queue for an application pool before rejecting future requests. The default value is 1000.

Comment: @DingPeng thanks, that property looks like it might of been the trigger, I've updated it to 5,000.  I imagine with a large burst of traffic which we do get sometimes this queue length may get filled.  Would our next step then be to upgrade the spec of the server to handle more requests?

Comment: Yes. If the amount of concurrency is particularly large, I suggest to upgrade the server configuration to increase the speed of processing requests.